# What is a professional format for blackbox debugging someone else’s app and submitting a report to them?

Tags: issue-tracking, bug-report

The idea is that if an app I like periodically has noticeable bugs or issues, and it’s commercial, not open source (in this case, AirBNB, but I feel this way often towards many apps), I would like to actually help them fix the bugs so the tool I rely on gets better and I don’t have to face malfunctions.

I could observe one bug, and send it in via email, but it would be nice to more systematically monitor it, see if it improves, get follow up if it is, or even investigate it a bit and provide information about what might be causing it.

Also, if I set myself to the task of communicating about a bug, I would be open to trying to find as many bugs as I can, to make the app better, since I’ve already gotten involved anyway.

Is there a standard format by which you blackbox debug someone else’s app and submit it as a clear, detailed report?

Comment: There are two very different, mostly unrelated questions in this post (the title + "Are there guides on how to try to check for bugs as thoroughly as possible? "). This makes it prone to be closed quickly as "needs more focus" (it already got one of those votes). Hence I took the freedom to remove the second one - but before asking it as a separate question, make sure yo cannot find any older question on the site which answers it.

Comment: ... let me add the "standard format" is always what the issue tracker of the project provides you with.  I am not going to write this as an answer, since it is mostly contained in [CandiedOrange's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/443981)

Comment: Step 1 is "find the organisation's public bug tracker". If they don't have one, then they're probably not going to accept submissions. Especially if it's a megacorp like AirBNB

Comment: Even glaring security bugs can often be quite hard to submit! Some organisations have "bug bounty" for those. Be careful, because freelance finding security bugs can occasionally get you prosecuted.

Comment: Does the app have a feedback mechanism?  Start there.

Answer (score 5):

Format? Well yeah.

> Here are the 6 things you need to include in an effective bug ticket:
>
> 1. Title — a searchable and unique title provides the developer a general understanding of the bug before clicking into it.
>    For example: Application crash on ‘Sign Up’ button click
> 2. Description — a brief description about the issue to provide the developer with some context of what the issue is and what they should be looking for.
>    For example: When a user tries to sign up for an account, then the application crashes and the user is unable to create an account.
> 3. Steps to reproduce — explain the steps the developer will take to replicate the bug. This is important because a developer can’t fix a bug they can’t reproduce.
>    For example: Go to registration page > fill in required fields > click on ‘Sign Up’ CTA > application crashes
> 4. Expected result — describe what you expect to happen when interacting with the feature.
>    For example: Given a user is on the registration page, when they’ve filled in the required fields and click on the ‘Sign Up’ CTA, then the user has successfully signed up for an account.
> 5. Actual result — describe the error, flaw, or failure that is taking place when interacting with the feature.
>    For example: Given a user is on the registration page, when they’ve filled in the required fields and click on the ‘Sign Up’ CTA, then the application crashes and the user is unable to create an account.
> 6. A Visual — providing a visual helps the developer understand what the exact issue is without any investigation on their end. This can significantly increase the speed of fixing the bug.
>    For example: a screenshot, video, or any visual.
> 7. Priority — unfortunately bugs can be found often and are not equally as important to fix. Identifying the priority will ensure that developers are addressing the work that is most important first.
>    For example: blocker, major, high, medium, low, etc.
>
> [medium.com - How to write a bug ticket — a beginners guide](https://medium.com/coderbyte/how-to-write-a-bug-ticket-a-beginners-guide-c93499082c3f)

But if you want to "more systematically monitor it" than you get from email you should see if the project already has a bug reporting / tracking system set up where they [may](https://support.github.com/contact/bug-report) or [may not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306075/bug-report-submitting) have already decided on a format for you. Submit your findings through that.

Comment: Not priority. If it's a cosmetic issue I'll tag it as a cosmetic issue; otherwise, including a priority is just silly because the developer/manager will choose their own priority and ignore yours.

Comment: @user253751 Priority is one to consider when you're the developer designing the ticketing system.